# Manage host iptables from docker container

Tags: docker, networking, iptables

I want to be able to see host iptables from inside a docker container. Not necessarily manage it, maybe a read-only iptables would be enough. I already gave --cap-add=NET_ADMIN and network mode is set to `host`, but still iptables is showing empty from inside container. More precisely, it seems to be a different iptables namespace or something like that. I'm able to add new rules from container's inside but that has no effect on host iptables, of course.

```
root@host:~# iptables -xnvL OUTPUT 
# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1104394 packets, 407916631 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   16498  3125381            all  --  *      *       8.8.8.8         0.0.0.0/0           
  107211 59743643            all  --  *      *       192.168.0.1          0.0.0.0/0
```

```
root@host:~# docker exec ct_monitor_1 iptables -xnvL OUTPUT
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 33081662 packets, 12617923760 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  206142 41989385            all  --  *      *       1.1.1.1         0.0.0.0/0           
 3686279 1919571839            all  --  *      *       172.0.0.1          0.0.0.0/0
```

(rules are fake, just to show that containers has different iptables)

Thanks!

## UPDATE

I noticed that the problem happens in host with Ubuntu 22.04 and docker container ubuntu <=20.04.

To clarify, I'm giving more context.

Host:

```
root@host:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

root@zitz:~# iptables -nvL OUTPUT
# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 437K packets, 229M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 285K  142M            all  --  *      *       8.8.8.8         0.0.0.0/0           
 120K   83M            all  --  *      *       192.168.0.1          0.0.0.0/0
```

**Working example**, notice that im using `ubuntu:jammy-20221003`

```
root@zitz:~# docker run --rm -it --network=host --cap-add=NET_ADMIN ubuntu:jammy-20221003 bash
root@zitz:/# apt -qq -y update && apt install -qq -y iptables
root@zitz:/# iptables -nvL OUTPUT
# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 436K packets, 229M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 285K  142M            all  --  *      *       8.8.8.8         0.0.0.0/0           
 120K   82M            all  --  *      *       192.168.0.1          0.0.0.0/0
```

**Non-working example**, i'm using any version of ubuntu lower or equal to 20.04

```
root@zitz:~# docker run --rm -it --network=host --cap-add=NET_ADMIN ubuntu:focal bash
root@zitz:/# apt -qq update && apt install -y -qqq iptables
.
.
.
root@zitz:/# iptables -nvL OUTPUT
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 148K packets, 53M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

iptables is "empty" in those cases

## Update 2

I think that my problem is related to this: https://serverfault.com/questions/1097499/warning-iptables-legacy-tables-present-use-iptables-legacy-save-to-see-them

Comment: One of Docker's key features is to give each container an isolated network environment.  This sounds like you want to directly manage the host network environment, and you might not want this isolation at all.  Can you run this process directly on the host, not in a container?

Comment: I could, but I prefer not to. We use a docker container to run monitoring services in each host. Using containers give as some advantages that we prefer to maintain. Some time ago, we had this on the host, but we move towards this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--network=host` is all you need. If you use `--network=host`, all network interfaces, including all the `iptables` is shared.

The difference, as you found out, is in user-space. Your host system is using nftables, not iptables.